# How to resolve Micro Frontend Shell app throwing 'not a known element' error for child Micro app?

Tags: angular, typescript, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, nx-workspace

I have all the appropriate modules imported in both the Shell(parent) app and Micro(child) app yet I get the error; specifically in my case 'mat-chip-list' is not a known element only when I launch the Shell(parent) app.

Is there a configuration I must have in my: webpack.config.js or nx.json or project.json or angular.json?

Modules:
Image 1: [App Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEtjW.png), Image 2: [Shell App Module Import Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/039X8.png), Image 3: [Shell App Module Export Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzWqA.png), Image 4: [sharedModule Import Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhPCe.png), Image 5: [SharedModule Export Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D24uJ.png), Image 6: [Material Module Import Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt3gl.png), Image 7: [Export Module Export Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkKZ3.png)

Comment: Share your routing and module files

Comment: @SatishSingh see images provided above in the description